# why does transmission bittorrent client still send and receive with zero download/upload speed!

Tags: networking, bittorrent, transmission, traffic

this is my network traffic with vnstat:

```
 ^                                                  r                          
  |                                                  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                               r  r                          
  |                                         r  r  r  r                          
  |                              t rt rt rt rt rt rt rt                         
 -+---------------------------------------------------------------------------> 
  |  15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14    

 h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB)      h  rx (KiB)   tx (KiB) 
15          0          0    23      23994      40915    07    1305794     175924
16       8487       1375    00     129206     203168    08      95179      98313
17          0          0    01     147492     192614    09      96384     109808
18          0          0    02     199779     192173    10      95519     112443
19          0          0    03     206705     204136    11      77934      89830
20          0          0    04     264584     205402    12      66171      69969
21      47189      55511    05     292691     206276    13      80901      88811
22      31564      53650    06    1048066     187709    14       5890       2730
```

from 00 to 07 I was downloading using transmission bittorent
from 08 to 13 I put download/upload speed limit on zero and nothing was downloading
and at 14 I closed transmission bittorrent

there are two things I do not understand :

1. why is there still network traffic from 07 to 13 while I limited speeds to zero?
2. I limited upload speed from 00 to 07 but bittorrent has uploaded about 200000 KiB per hour

somebody please explain me why is this happening?

## **P.S**

pausing torrents give same result as putting limit on speed, there is still traffic:
vnstat while bittorrent is open and all are paused

```
                          rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                      170 KiB  |         143 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max              68 kbit/s  |       52 kbit/s
      average           48.57 kbit/s  |    40.86 kbit/s
          min              36 kbit/s  |       28 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                       1562  |            1470
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                 71 p/s  |          68 p/s
      average                 55 p/s  |          52 p/s
          min                 43 p/s  |          39 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                    28 seconds
```

now I closed the bittorrent and results

```
                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                        3 KiB  |           4 KiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max               8 kbit/s  |        4 kbit/s
      average            0.96 kbit/s  |     1.28 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        0 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                         32  |              40
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                  7 p/s  |           7 p/s
      average                  1 p/s  |           1 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           0 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                    25 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say for sure. But what you're limiting is the actual file transfer. I'd guess that Transmission would still update the trackers at a regular interval. That shouldn't be too much data, but if you have many active torrents, it'll grow. Perhaps it keeps updating the list of peers as well.

Comment: I do not think it's true! there is my reason in my post

Comment: Does it show active connections?

Comment: do you mean vnstat?

Comment: No, I meant Transmission. Connections require bandwidth, even if you're not transferring actual data. I don't know if Transmission will disconnect when you set a limit of 0 or if it will still keep the connections open. In other words; there can be many reasons why it still uses bandwidth.